# When should 'static bound' be added to trait definition

Tags: rust

Can anyone explain the use of `'static` here for me? I see this code, but I don't understand how it is used.

```rs
// When should 'static bound' be added to trait definitions
pub trait FinalitySyncPipeline: 'static + Clone + Debug + Send + Sync {
    /// Name of the finality proofs source.
    const SOURCE_NAME: &'static str;
    /// Name of the finality proofs target.
    const TARGET_NAME: &'static str;

    /// Headers we're syncing are identified by this hash.
    type Hash: Eq + Clone + Copy + Send + Sync + Debug;
    /// Headers we're syncing are identified by this number.
    type Number: relay_utils::BlockNumberBase;
    /// Type of header that we're syncing.
    type Header: SourceHeader<Self::Number>;
    /// Finality proof type.
    type FinalityProof: FinalityProof<Self::Number>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a trait bound, it means the type does not contain any non-static references. Eg. the receiver can hold on to the type for as long as they want and it will never become invalid until they drop it.

See: [Static - Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html)

Comment: This answer provides a correct explanation of the _meaning_ of the `'static` lifetime bound. In addition to that, the _reason_ why one typically wants to require `'static` is to be able to pass the value to a non-scoped thread (which requires `'static` values, as the thread can run indefinitely), or to store it in a global or thread-local container. Since the trait also requires `Send` and `Sync`, the use in threads is the most likely motivation for `'static`.