# Append futures with generic output to mutable reference of FuturesUnordered

Tags: rust

I have the following scenario where I am trying to add futures to `peers` which directly resolve to `A` inside the function `test`:

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

use core::pin::Pin;
use std::rc::Rc;
use core::fmt::Debug;
use tokio::io::AsyncRead;
use tokio::io::AsyncWrite;
use core::cell::RefCell;
use futures::stream::FuturesUnordered;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct State {
    foo: String
}

pub async fn test<A: AsyncWrite + AsyncRead + Unpin + Debug + 'static>(
    peers: &mut FuturesUnordered<Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = A>>>>,
) {
    
    let pp: Vec<Rc<RefCell<A>>> = Vec::new();
    for p in pp {
        let p = Rc::try_unwrap(p).unwrap();
        let p: A = p.into_inner();
        peers.push(Box::pin(async move {
            p
        }));
    }
}
```

[rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=24272b33dabc697f70fdd3954c304efe)

But I want to remove the `'static` lifetime requirement for `A` since I want to dispose of it once a future in `peers` has been awaited.

If I remove the generic type parameter and replace it with `u64` I have the following:

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

use core::pin::Pin;
use std::rc::Rc;
use core::fmt::Debug;
use tokio::io::AsyncRead;
use tokio::io::AsyncWrite;
use core::cell::RefCell;
use futures::stream::FuturesUnordered;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct State {
    foo: String
}

pub async fn test(
    peers: &mut FuturesUnordered<Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = u64>>>>,
) {
    
    let pp: Vec<Rc<RefCell<u64>>> = Vec::new();
    for p in pp {
        let p = Rc::try_unwrap(p).unwrap();
        let p: u64 = p.into_inner();
        peers.push(Box::pin(async move {
            p
        }));
    }
}
```

which works fine.

Why do I need to add the `'static` lifetime for it to work with generics? Is there a better solution to my problem here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should 'static bound' be added to trait definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67814450/when-should-static-bound-be-added-to-trait-definition)

Comment: See also: https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program

Answer (score 1):

`'static` here does not mean that the lifetime of `A` is the whole program but that `A` does not contain any references that are shorter than `'static` or in other words `A` is a completely owned struct. It doesn't prevent `A` from being freed.